# how does the below code work??? explain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

```
return Math.Min(FirstOfPage + PageSize - 1, TotalCount);
```

explain the code please

Comment: No. First, there's no context for any of your variables given. Second, figure it out on your own, or you won't learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returns either the last record number on the page, or the total number of records, whichever is smaller.  Probably to keep from returning more records than is available on the last page.